# How to reformat code to output properly?

Tags: c

I have code that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        int x;

        if (argc != 2) {
                printf("error\n");
                return -1;
        }
        char *ptr = argv[1];
        int count[256] = {0};
        while (*ptr) {
                if(!isdigit(*ptr)){
                        count[(unsigned char)*ptr]++;
                        ptr++;
                }
                else{
                        printf("error\n");
                        return -1;
                }
        }
        int i;
        int compCount = 0;
        for (i = 0 ; i != 256 ; i++) {
                if (count[i]) {
                //      compCount += printf("%c%d",i,count[i]);
                        compCount +=2;
                }

        }

        int j;
        if(compCount > strlen(argv[1])){
                printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
        }else{

                for(j=0; j!=256;j++){
                        if(count[j]){
                                printf("%c%d",j,count[j]);
                        }
                }

        }
}
```

I am trying to work through some test cases that I was provided. For example, my code breaks at this test case:

- INPUT: ./program aabccccccggeeecccccd
- EXPECTED: a2b1c6g2e3c5d1
- OUTPUT: a2b1c11d1e3g2

Any suggestions as to how I can fix this?

Comment: You're counting all occurrences of the letters in the string, but it looks like you should only be counting consecutive occurrences of the letters. You're solving for the wrong problem.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Re "*Any suggestions as to how I can fix this?*", Write a program that solves performs the desired task instead of using someone else's program that doesn't.

Comment: Count the repetition of letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// dst needs to at least strlen(src)*2+1 in size.
void encode(char* dst, const char* src) {
    while (1) {
       char ch = *src;
       if (!ch) {
          *dst = 0;
          return;
       }

       size_t count = 1;
       while (*(++src) == ch)
          ++count;

       *(dst++) = ch;
       dst += sprintf(dst, "%zu", count);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   if (argc != 2) {
      fprintf(stderr, "usage\n");
      return 1;
   }

   const char* src = argv[1];
   char* dst = malloc(strlen(src)*2+1);
   encode(dst, src);
   printf("%s\n", dst);
   free(dst);
   return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -o a a.c

$ ./a aabccccccggeeecccccd
a2b1c6g2e3c5d1

$ ./a abc
a1b1c1
```

Comment: Huh? As I showed, it compiles cleanly and produces the correct result. What did you do wrong?

Comment: Getting a bunch of unknown types, incompatible declaration of built in function

Comment: I tried you gcc line as well but still got some errors

Comment: Any way you can point me in the direction of editing this piece of code to say, if the string-length a1b1c1d1 (8) > abcd (4 - original statement)... then output only 'abcd'

Comment: Are you seriously asking how to compare the length of two strings?!

Comment: Well yes - it shouldnt be embarrassing as I am brand new to C... so i am comparing the length of dst (our new output) to src?

Comment: Comments are not the place to ask new questions. And you obviously didn't try to find the answer yourself since that's a trivial thing to find. It's even done once in the code I posted!

Answer (score -1):

The code does not even compile, because it had 2 errors. The main one was that the esdigit function was defined but the liberia that mentions this procedure, which is ctype (`#include <ctype.h>`), was not included.

Another error was that a variable x was declared but not used

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *ptr = argv[1];
    int count[256] = {0};
    while (*ptr) {
        if(!isdigit(*ptr)){
            count[(unsigned char)*ptr]++;
            ptr++;
        }
        else{
            printf("error\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    int i;
    size_t compCount = 0;
    for (i = 0 ; i != 256 ; i++) {
        if (count[i]) {
            compCount +=2;
        }
    }

    int j;
    if(compCount > strlen(argv[1])){
        printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    }else{
        for(j=0; j!=256;j++){
            if(count[j]){
                printf("%c%d",j,count[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still produces `a2b1c11d1e3g2` instead of `a2b1c6g2e3c5d1`.

Comment: Produces `abc` instead of `a1b1c1` for `abc`.